# It seems it is not possible to increase audio recording volume on Android. So is it possible to modify the audio file afterwards?

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I have a recording application and the audio is recording too low.

I see from several postings that it is not easy (possible?) to increase the recording volume.

Therefore I am thinking of a hack - is it possible to take the (low) audio file and transform it to increase the audio volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to modify the action of the volume buttons themselves, try this:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html

Comment: Thanks - there is a lot going on in that article - can you tell me specifically what you were referring to?

Comment: `@Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
   AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
   float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
     .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
   // Is the sound loaded already?
   if (loaded) {
    soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
    Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
   }
  }
  return false;`